# why does this formula find the line from a point to another point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given two points $(x,y)$ and $(n,m)$, and the length between them $l$, why do the points $(x,y)$ and $(x+h,x+s)$ make a line that is part of the previous line,where $h=\frac{x-n}{l}$ and $s=\frac{y-m}{l}$?

Comment: Because the vector $v=\langle x-n, y-m\rangle$ points in the direction of the line, and $u=\langle h, s\rangle=\frac{1}{\ell}\langle x-n, y-m\rangle$ is just a scalar multiple of $v$. (In fact, it is the normalization of $v$.) So adding $v$, or $u$, to $\langle x,y\rangle$ produces a vector lying along the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without loss of generality, set $(x,y) = (0,0)$. I find it helps sometimes to get rid of some variables.

Now, we have a line from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$ and we are wondering if $(-\frac{n}{l},-\frac{m}{l})$ is on the same line. It should be pretty clear at this point that it is, but just to make sure, the line we're on is:

$$y = \frac{m}{n}x$$

And

$$\frac{m}{n}\times-\frac{n}{l} = -\frac{m}{l}$$

Which is our new $y$ coordinate.